# Cmake errors while installing ViZDoom

Tags: python, linux, cmake

I am trying to install ViZDoom on Ubuntu system. I am following the steps given the following link https://github.com/mwydmuch/ViZDoom/blob/master/doc/Building.md.

As shown below:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libsdl2-dev libjpeg-dev \
nasm tar libbz2-dev libgtk2.0-dev cmake git libfluidsynth-dev libgme-dev \
libopenal-dev timidity libwildmidi-dev unzip

sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip
pip3 install numpy

sudo apt-get install julia
julia
julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.add("CxxWrap")

pip install git+https://github.com/mwydmuch/ViZDoom.git

mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON -DBUILD_JAVA=ON -DBUILD_LUA=ON -DBUILD_JULIA=ON
make
```

However, when I do this

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_PYTHON3=ON -DBUILD_JAVA=ON -DBUILD_LUA=ON -DBUILD_JULIA=ON
```

I am getting the following error:

```
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   system
--   date_time
--   chrono
--   regex
--   iostreams
--   atomic
CMake Deprecation Warning at cmake_modules/CreateLaunchers.cmake:48 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/vizdoom/CMakeLists.txt:13 (include)

-- Could NOT find GME (missing: GME_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Using system zlib
-- Using system jpeg library
-- Using system bzip2 library
-- Using internal gme library
-- /usr/include
-- /usr/include
-- /home/tie/ViZDoom/src/vizdoom/lzma/C
-- Could not find FMOD include files
-- Could NOT find SndFile (missing: SNDFILE_LIBRARY SNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find MPG123 (missing: MPG123_LIBRARIES MPG123_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Selected assembler: /usr/bin/as
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   system
--   date_time
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Fluid synth libs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so
-- pybind11 v2.8.1 
CMake Error at src/lib_julia/CMakeLists.txt:1 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindJlCxx.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "JlCxx", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "JlCxx" with any of
  the following names:

    JlCxxConfig.cmake
    jlcxx-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "JlCxx" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "JlCxx_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "JlCxx"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tie/ViZDoom/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/tie/ViZDoom/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I also install Julia successfully：
[image]

I think that there is CMake error or some version mismatch error but being new to it, I am unable to resolve it.

Comment: "I am following the steps given the following link" - What **exact steps** have you performed? Have you performed steps described as "To build Julia binding you first need to install CxxWrap package by running julia and using Pkg.add("CxxWrap") command ..."? Please, [edit] your question post and add those steps to it which you **actually** performed. It could be that you actually missed some steps noted in the documentation, but we could only guess which one you have missed.

Comment: I had installed CxxWrap package，but also has errors.

Comment: It seems you forget to pass variable `JlCxx_DIR` to `cmake`, as noted in the documentation. Also, you are trying to build and install ViZDoom **manually**, but the command `pip install git+https://github.com/mwydmuch/ViZDoom.git` **installs** ViZDoom to your machine. As a result, it will be **two installations** of ViZDoom on your machine, which is probably not what do you want.

Comment: Your help was very much appreciated, thank you very much! But what can I try now?Delete them then install a new one? Look forward to your kind advice.

Comment: If you want to remove the package installed via `pip install`, then just type `pip uninstall <package_name>`.